# Is Frenet-Serret frame valid for non-natural parametrized curves when one normalizes the tangent vector?

Tags: differential-geometry

When one have a curve $\beta(s)$ which is parametrized by arc length (has natural parametrization) one is able to obtain the tangent, normal and binormal vectors by using Frenet-Serret frame equations:

$T = \beta'(s)$, $N=\frac{T'(s)}{|T'(s)|}$, $B = T \times N$

But are those formulas valid for non-regular parametrizations when one normalizes the tangent vector?

$T=\frac{\beta'(s)}{|\beta'(s)|}$, $N$ and $B$ are calculated as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes, as the Wikipedia article says at the end.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas#Other_expressions_of_the_frame)

Comment: Oh, silly me. Did not see that, thank you! :)